# SVG images in IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, svg

[svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) doesn't work in Internet Explorer when the object tag is added to the DOM after the page has finished loading.

Flow:

- Page finishes loading
- User clicks a button
- Path of SVG is returned
- It is dynamically inserted into DOM

This works in all browsers except Internet Explorer.

How to make it work?

Comment: Can you provide a simple test file (with valid referenced SVG) showing this problem? Have you considered fetching the SVG source and [appending that document to the page](http://groups.google.com/group/svg-web/browse_thread/thread/363d599b7eb5a517) instead of as a referenced element?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need adobe svg viewer as a plugin

Comment: SVG works natively in all modern browsers,...and "works" in newer IE, just has some scaling issues.